# Compare two different dataframes based on multiple row conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes containing different information about the same patients. I need to use dataframe 1 to filter dataframe 2 so that dataframe 2 will only keep its integer patient row values if there is an integer value in `df_1` for the same `chromosome`, `strand`, `elementloc`, and `patient`. If there is an `NaN` value in df_1, I'd like to put `NaN` in `df_2` in that same location. For `NaN` values already in `df_2`, I'd like to leave them as NaN.

So with `df_1` and `df_2` like:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'chromosome': [1, 1, 5, 4],
                     'strand': ['-', '-', '+', '-'],
                     'elementloc': [4991, 8870, 2703, 9674],
                     'Patient1_Reads': ['NaN', 25, 50, 'NaN'],
                     'Patient2_Reads': [35, 200, 'NaN', 500]})

print(df_1)                                                                    
   chromosome strand  elementloc Patient1_Reads Patient2_Reads
0           1      -        4991            NaN             35
1           1      -        8870             25            200
2           5      +        2703             50            NaN
3           4      -        9674            NaN            500


df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'chromosome': [1, 1, 5, 4],
                     'strand': ['-', '-', '+', '-'],
                     'elementloc': [4991, 8870, 2703, 9674],
                     'Patient1_PSI': [0.76, 0.35, 0.04, 'NaN'],
                     'Patient2_PSI': [0.89, 0.15, 0.47, 0.32]})
print(df_2)                                                                      
   chromosome strand  elementloc   Patient1_PSI    Patient2_PSI
0           1      -        4991           0.76            0.89
1           1      -        8870           0.35            0.15
2           5      +        2703           0.04            0.47
3           4      -        9674            NaN            0.32
```

**I would like new `df_2` to look like:**

```
   chromosome strand  elementloc  Patient1_PSI  Patient2_PSI
0           1      -        4991           NaN          0.89
1           1      -        8870          0.35          0.15
2           5      +        2703          0.04           NaN
3           4      -        9674           NaN          0.32
```

Comment: Does both the dataframes always contain corresponding columns for each patient, for example if `PatientX_Reads` is present in `df1` then will the corresponding `PatientX_PSI` is always present in `df2`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, yes! That being said, I need to make sure the entries of chromosome, strand, elemtloc are identical in order to compare PatientX_Reads and PatientX_PSI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:**

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['chromosome', 'strand', 'elementloc'])

r_cols = df3.columns[df3.columns.str.endswith('_Reads')]
p_cols = r_cols.str.strip('Reads') + 'PSI'

df3[p_cols] = df3[p_cols].mask(df3[r_cols].isna().to_numpy())
df3 = df3.drop(r_cols, 1)
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to create a merged dataframe `df3` obtained by merging the dataframes `df1` and `df2` on `['chromosome', 'strand', 'elementloc']`.

```
# print(df3)
   chromosome strand  elementloc  Patient1_Reads  Patient2_Reads  Patient1_PSI  Patient2_PSI
0           1      -        4991             NaN            35.0          0.76          0.89
1           1      -        8870            25.0           200.0          0.35          0.15
2           5      +        2703            50.0             NaN          0.04          0.47
3           4      -        9674             NaN           500.0           NaN          0.32
```

STEP B: Use [`.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) to get the columns in `df3` which ends with `_Reads` we call this columns `r_cols`, then use this `_Reads` columns to obtain the corresponding `_PSI` columns we call this columns `p_cols`.

```
# print(r_cols)
Index(['Patient1_Reads', 'Patient2_Reads'], dtype='object')

# print(p_cols)
Index(['Patient1_PSI', 'Patient2_PSI'], dtype='object')
```

STEP C: Use [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) on the `_Reads` columns to obtain the *boolean mask*, then use this mask along with [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to fill the correponding `NaN` values in `_PSI` columns. Finally use [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to drop the `_Reads` column from the merged datframe `df3` to get the desired result:

```
# print(df3)
   chromosome strand  elementloc  Patient1_PSI  Patient2_PSI
0           1      -        4991           NaN          0.89
1           1      -        8870          0.35          0.15
2           5      +        2703          0.04           NaN
3           4      -        9674           NaN          0.32
```